# Split string based on two delimiter in C#

Tags: c#, linq

**Question**- I am having a file(info.ref) that contains information in a specific format (refrence id |email addresses) e.g.:

```
ref1|a@a.com,b@b.com,c@c.com   
ref2|c@c.com,d@d.com
```

I also fetch refrence id from another file (say ref1).I need to iterate through this file and then want to send email to all email id`s assosiated with this refrence Id.

What I tried-

```
 using (var streamReader = new StreamReader("info.ref"))
                            {
                                string line1="";
                                while((line1 = streamReader.ReadLine()) != null)
                                {
                                    var parameters =
                                       from line11 in line1
                                       let split = line1.Split('|')
                                       select new { name = split.First(), value = split.Skip(1) };

                                   //email logic to be written


                                }
```

**Problem**-How to get email list from this "parameters".

**Note**-I understand that I can split the string with "|" as delimiters and again split with "," as delimiter and store in array.But can someone please guide what is wrong with the code I have written and how to retreive email addresses?and which is better way?.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't split the emails by comma yet and you don't need the LINQ query in  the loop:

```
string[] tokens = line1.Split('|');
if(tokens.Length >= 2)
{
    string name = tokens[0];
    string[] emails = tokens[1].Split(',');
}
```

If you are learning LINQ, you could use `File.ReadLines` and following query:

```
var allInfos = from line in System.IO.File.ReadLines("info.ref")
               let tokens = line.Split('|')
               where tokens.Length >=  2
               select new { name = tokens[0], emails = tokens[1].Split(',') };

foreach(var info in allInfos)
    Console.WriteLine("Name:{0} Emails{1}", info.name, String.Join(",", info.emails));
```

Comment: Thanks,but how to use this email list?I am not able to get that I mean "parameter.emails" is not allowed.

Comment: I didn't get it. You are selecting chars (line11) from `line1`.. So you are splitting `line1` several times without reason (performance issue).

Comment: @vish1990: note that i've edited my answer. I don't see why you need that LINQ query at all.

Comment: Thanks.i have accepted this one and the reason i was using Linq is to make some concepts clear and work with Linq a bit.Was just curious how we can do this by Linq.Between great thanks.

Comment: @vish1990: i've added a LINQ approach in case you are learning it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also split by multiple separators (assuming that ref cannont contain `,` char)):

```
var emails = line1.Split('|', ',').Skip(1); //skipping ref
```

or:

```
var splitted = line1.Split('|', ',');
var paramerers = 
       new 
       {
           name = splitted.FirstOrDefault(), //for case of empty line
           value = spliited.Skip(1)
       };

//usage
var emails = parameters.value.ToArray(); // f.e.
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers.I wanted emails associated with referenceId.so need both those parameter as output,not just emails.taking your answer as lead,will try to figure out.Thanks

Comment: So, I added antoher apporach :)